# Manage long-running connection to Twitter streaming API from java EE application

Tags: java, rest, twitter, jakarta-ee, ejb

I need to create a long-running connection from within a Java EE6 application to the [Twitter streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) and also be able to monitor and re-establish the connection on failure.

I've run up a test with Jersey JAX-RS and OAuth as follows and this handles the streaming data as I would like.

```
WebResource resource = client.resource(STATUS_URI);
resource.addFilter(oauthFilter);
ClientResponse clientResponse = resource.get(ClientResponse.class);
InputStream is = clientResponse.getEntityInputStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
boolean more = true;
while (more) {
    String jsonTweet = r.readLine();
    //send tweet to JMS queue
    ..... 
}
```

I've tried running the above code in a singleton '@PostConstruct' method but it blocks and the application does not load properly.

My question is what would be the recommended way to initialise the connection from within a Java EE environment on application startup and then monitor + re-connect on errors without directly creating new threads?

Answer (score 0):

> recommended way to initialise the
>   connection from within a Java EE
>   environment on application startup

- You can use `@Service` to create Singleton MBean(JBoss Specific implementation), but still I prefer `@Startup` & `@Singleton` to get things done at application deployment for portability with server.

> monitor + re-connect on errors without
>   directly creating new threads?

- ThreadPoolExecutor : An ExecutorService that executes each submitted task using one of possibly several pooled threads, normally configured using Executors factory methods.

In exception, tasks can be resubmitted to executor service, task may comprise of monitoring, reconnecting the connection etc.

Comment: I thought it was against the spec to use Executor from within an EJB?

Comment: Yes, it may interfere but have to handle it well if used. Aternatively you can use JMS for the same purpose.